# MongoDB the difference between db.getCollection.find and db.tablename.find?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

What is the difference between:

```
db.getCollection('booking').find()
```

and

```
db.booking.find()
```

Are they exactly the same, or when should I use which one?

```
db.getCollection('booking').find({_id:"0J0DR"})

db.booking.find({_id:"0J0DR"})
```

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getCollection/ that's all you need

Comment: That one explained that insertOne does not work, or something :-D  To be honest docs.mongodb.com sucks, their examples are horrible, their descriptions unclear (you cant just copy paste and try it).  The examples I find here on stackoverflow are so much better!!  Anyway it looks like that these are exactly the same.

Comment: The example in the docs is correct. You can't do an insertOne on db.auth but you can do it if you use db.getCollection("auth") (which is obviously not the same). The docs are quite good in my opinion.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, they are exactly the same and you can use either.

The first form `db.getCollection(collectionName).find()` becomes handy when your collection name contains special characters that will otherwise render the other syntax redundant.

**Example:**
Suppose your collection has a name that begin with `_` or matches a database shell method or has a space, then you can use `db.getCollection("booking trips").find()` or `db["booking trips"].find()` where doing `db.booking trips.find()` is impossible.

Comment: Thanks - the whole "sets a cursor" thing in their docus confused me. In MemoDB you can set a cursor and then step thru rows with one command and get all rows with another :)

Comment: True, some parts of the docs need attention or miss some salient info which you can then supplement here on SO :)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using [db.collection()](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html) to either as it will work on nonexistent collections, which is particularly useful when for example creating the first user in a `users` collection that doesn't yet exist.

```
db.collection('users').findOneAndUpdate(...) // Won't throw even if the collection doesn't exist yet
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous answers, on the shell, they might be exactly the same but in real IDE (like PyCharm), db.getCollection(collectionName) gives you back the whole doculment even with out the find() method.